# Мне нужно из столбца из таблицы вытащить значение, которое встречается чаще остальных

Tags: python, pandas

Мне нужно из столбца из таблицы вытащить значение, которое встречается чаще остальных. У меня есть таблица дата фрейм df и мне нужно сделать это с помощью pandas

Comment: Можете добавить небольшой пример данных? Может быть вы уже какой-то код попытались написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас может быть не одно значение, а несколько, т.к. какие-то значения могут встречаться одинаковое число раз.

Чтобы найти их все, можно использовать метод `.mode()`, который возвращает для столбца новый столбец, в котором остались только те значения, которые встречаются максимальное число раз.

Используйте вот так:

```
df[номер_нужного_столбца].mode()
```